# WP-Page-Navi and infinitive scroll paging issue

Tags: wordpress, pagination

on the homepage i have a custom query that list posts from some category. It is like a small widget with latest news. It show latest 5 news and then it shows SHOW MORE button. Once you click show more it open next 5 news etc etc. I made it with combination of wp-page-navo plugin (for pagination) and Catch Infinite Scroll to have laod more not default 1 2 3 4 (regular) pagination. It works fine but now i get paged urls homepage/page/1 homepage/page/2 etc. That cause me a lot of SEO issues because i have that same widget on multiple pages.

Can i still have funcionality that i want but without creating those extra paged urls?
Thanks.

```
<?php
    global $paged, $wp_query, $wp;
    $args = wp_parse_args($wp->matched_query);
    if ( !empty ( $args['paged'] ) ) {
    $wp_query->set('paged', $args['paged']);
    $paged = $args['paged'];
    }

    $postsPerPage = wp_is_mobile() ? 3 : 20;

    $the_press = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage, 
        'paged'=> get_query_var('paged') ));
    while ($the_press->have_posts()) : $the_press->the_post();
        ?>         

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<nav class="pagination-block">
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array('query'=> $the_press));} ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</nav>
```